# How can i suppress xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" using JAXB

Tags: xml, jaxb

I am running into an issue with JAXB marshaller. According to the document when 
@XmlElement(required = true) which is nillable = false as default, an instance of null is omitted, but instead i see 

in the generated xml, how should i let JAXB omit "ExternalEventId" altogether from xml.

Comment: I'm in the same spot you are I think, albeit a little late to the party.  Did you ever find a solution to your problem?  If I manage to find a solution, I'll post it here.  The solution by @IanRoberts didn't fix my problem (required is already set to false).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to represent `null` by the complete absence of the element then simply use `required=false` (the default).  If null values are to be allowed at all then the element must be either `required=false` or `nillable=true` - in the former case `null` is represented by omitting the element, in the latter by `xsi:nil`.

A `null` value for a property that is neither optional nor nillable makes no sense.

Comment: I have my element defined as                                   @XmlElement(name = "ExternalEventId")
    protected String externalEventId;                                                         I have not specified that it is required, neither have i specified nillable=true, in that case null value will be just omitted, but i see <ExternalEventId xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/> in the xml